# Euclidean Distance Vectorization Problem MNIST [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, knn

I am trying to calculate Euclidean Distance for MNIST data set.

[image]

```
X_Train = 60,000*784 and   

 X_Test = 10,000*784

D= No. of Columns, 
M= rows of training set and 
N = rows of test set
```

I've done

```
X_test_sq = sum(X_test(:,1:784),2)
```

and same for training set and I get 10,000*1 and 60,000*1 vectors.
But I don't understand what XtestSqrR means and shouldn't X_cross be dot product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XtestSqrR is the sum squared distance (with respect to the origin of 0,0,...,0).  The distance along each dimension is: `sum( X(:,d).^2 )` (square first then sum); then you can sum across dimensions (d goes from 1 to 60,000).

Also I think the x means matrix multiplication, not cross product.  So a matrix of 60,000*784 multiplied by a matrix of (784*10,000), would be 60,000*10,000.

Comment: Xsqr = d.testX.^2 --------
Xtsqr = d.trainX.^2 --------
XtestSqr = sum(Xtsqr(:,784),2); // sum row vectors of matrix -----
 XtrainSqr = sum(Xtsqr(:,784),2); ------

now I have two column vectors 10,000*1 and 60,000*1 -----

Now comes turn of second sum for both but it says XtestSqr horizontally M times which is 60,000 but XtestSqr has only 1 column and even after transpose it has 10k

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit as i am very much confused with the dimensions . Thank You

Comment: alright I've done it. matlab took 20 mins to solve this . Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: Thanks for trying it!  There might be some speed ups you can get but ultimately I would suggest using C/C++.